# Sharepoint REST-Call shows no result

Tags: rest, sharepoint

i'm working with Sharepoint 2016 on premises. I have a site with two content editor webparts. Both are linked to html-files and should get their content by call to the Rest-API. The problem is, that only one webpart at a time shows its result. If i deactivate one webpart, the other shows its results.  There are no error messages. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share your code snippet. That would be more helpful..

Comment: It seems your success functions have same name, so there is clash. so only one will render at same time.

Comment: That solved the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :)